# Use Google APIs Node.js client library with AppEngine Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-nodejs-client

I've coded an Java App Engine app that uses Cloud Endpoints. I want to talk to these endpoints from a Node.js app. Is it possible to use the google-api-nodejs-client for this purpose?

I've already tried this:

```
var googleapis = require('googleapis');

googleapis
    .discover('myapiname', 'v1dev', {baseDiscoveryUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/'})
    .execute(function(err, client) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(client);
        client.myapiname.domains.list().execute(function(err, resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    });
```

But the library does not discover my endpoint, the callback returns null for `err` and `client` looks like this:

```
{ clients: [],
  ops: {},
  authClient: null,
  undefined: 
   { apiMeta: '<html><head><title>Error 404</title></head>\n<body><h2>Error 404</h2></body>\n</html>',
     authClient: null,
     defaultParams: null } }
```

I've replaced my real api name with 'myapiname' and of course the URL `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/` is reachable (it returns me the right discovery JSON if I open it in the browser on the same computer).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the same code with code deployed on some vm on google app engine. 
 I tried the same with our app engine url and it works like charm.